# Monitoring Db2 tablespace with partitioned table

Tags: db2, db2-luw

How to monitor allocation data in tablespaces with partitioned table?

I want to know when my tablespaces will fill up before creating new tablespaces with new partition.
When I perform command:

`db2pd -db DBTEST -tablespace`
I got information with tablespace Statistics: **UsablePgs** and **FreePgs**. 
The values remain the same even when I perform runstat on my table.
I thought that after runstat this value will grow.

Comment: Is this a programming question?  If not, it is better suited to dba.stackexchange.com .  Specify your Db2-version and fixpack. Specify whether each partition has dedicated tablespaces.  The stats will only change if the data in the partitions changed since the most recent run and your runstats options are appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The information returned by this call doesn't depend on runstats.
Think about this allocation info as "always current".

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `MON_GET_TABLESPACE`

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0053943.html